# Wrap to new line but do not wrap subsequent div elements

Tags: css

To wrap a div to a new line I use :

```
<div style="clear: both; padding-top: 10px;"></div>
```

But this wraps every other subsequent div. Can this code be amended so that just the sbusequent (first) div is wrapped to a new line but every other div remains on same line ?

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/m2cvv/

So keep the div with text "do not wrap this" on same line.

Code :

```
<div>test</div>
<div style="clear: both; padding-top: 10px;"></div>
<div>wrap this</div>
<div>do not wrap this</div>
```

Comment: Some fiddle with code for clarification would be nice.

Comment: I'm guessing you are targeting element using JS

Comment: Do you have other CSS or JavaScript code being applied? I'm failing to understand your question.

Comment: @j08691 does the fiddle make it clearer ?

Comment: So divs with 'test' and 'do not wrap' should be in one line..?

Comment: Without JavaScript nor changing the order of your elements I think it might be impossible to do what you're trying to achieve. Is there any reason why you can't just move the 'wrap this' div after all of the ones that are supposed to aligned. Also, are you dealing with responsive design here?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>test</div>
<div style="clear: both; padding-top: 10px;"></div>
<div style="display:inline;" >wrap this</div>
<div style="display:inline;">do not wrap this</div>
```

easiest way but not best way - try to avoid inline styles